# Need to know about this separate unidentified drive. (snapshots included)

Tags: windows, windows-10

The drive in red. I don't remember when I saw it first time. I thought it was a backup drive back then.

Can I remove this partition?

I can provide any further details if needed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the size of the partition that’s the WinRE partition. It’s trivial to remove the drive letter from that partition.  **DO NOT delete the partition**

Comment: @Ramhound Oh Dear. It seems I will have to protect it from attacks. Very many thanks.

Comment: Just remove them drive letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the size and that is a "local" disk and the WINRE marker file I would hazard a guess that it is either the EFI partition or a special utility partition that is created by 3rd party backup and/or partitioning software.

Normally such partitions don't get/need a drive-letter and are hidden, but Windows may accidentally attach a drive-letter anyway and in that case you will see it.

Using the Disk Administrator tool in Windows you can remove the drive-letter, but don't otherwise modify this partition because that may leave your computer un-bootable!